# calculating Power

Tags: power, power-electronics, ohms-law, watts

I wanted to ask, if I have a electrical component with a power rating of let's say 5W does this mean it would dissapate 10W after 2 hours and 15 W after 3 hours?? or is it correct to say it dissapates 5W per hour?

Comment: No.  power is an instantaneous value if you are interested in power dissipation over time you are talking energy.  Over 2 hours you could say the energy is 10 watt-hours however.  Energy is more commonly expressed in joules however: 1 joule is the energy required to dissipate 1 watt continuously  for 1 second.

Comment: Sounds like you're mistaking J for W and having trouble with time.

Comment: So if I have a 0.2 W resistor in a circuit after 2 hours how much power would it use

Comment: You must determine how much power is actually being consumed by the resistor, you can't just look at its maximum power rating. And if you multiply power times time you get **energy**.

Comment: @DanielBashy I literally just said that you are mistaking J for W, and then you proceed to keep doing it. I get the feeling that you'd love to get fed information via YT, so [here you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdbhnmA4M9g). Once you've seen that, read the answers, word for word, if you don't understand the answers, make comments to them stating exactly where in the answer you don't follow. - Do not keep making comments to your own question with further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl; dr version: Your math numbers are right, but your units need work, and we need to talk about power rating.

**Energy and Power**

What's missing is the concept of *energy* vs. *power*. Stated simply, energy is power * time. It is also proper to state that power is energy / time.

So about those units, then.

A unit of energy is the *Joule*, which is 1 Watt * 1 second. Unsurprisingly, it's also called a *Watt-second*, which may get you a dirty look from an SI nerd but it's equally valid.

A unit of power is the *Watt*, which is 1 Joule / 1 second.

Which brings us to another common unit, the *Watt-hour*, which is simply 1 Watt * 1 hour. It's what your utility meter uses. It is equal to 3600 Joules or 3600 Watt-seconds.

**Power Rating**

When a device has current passing through it, its resistance will cause power to be dissipated as heat. That is, W = I^2 * R (or, W = E^2/R).

What a '5W' resistor means is that 5W is the *maximum* dissipation that the component can handle without being destroyed by heat. It doesn't mean that it gives off 5 W all by itself. *That* figure depends on what current you're pushing through it, and the resistance of the component.

For example, a 5 Ohm resistor with 5 Volts across it will have 1 Amp passing through it, and will be dissipating 5W. And it will get hot in the process. Such a resistor will need to be a 5W rating to handle the heat. If you increase the voltage to 10V across it, 2A will be passing through it, and it will be dissipating 20W and thus will need to be a 20W (!) rating.

What? *20W*? Where does that come from? It's that I^2 (or E^2) term that will get you every time if you don't watch for it. Keep it in mind when you're thinking about how to size resistors.

**Tying It Together**

Your '5W' resistor will only use energy if you apply a voltage to it and force a current through it. The energy it uses is proportional to time, resistance and current-squared.

That is, E = t * W = t * (I^2 * R).

As we saw before, that 5 Ohm resistor with 1A flowing through it will be dissipating 5W as heat. Run it for an hour, it will use 5 Watt-hours. For 2 hours, 10 Watt-hours. And so forth.

Regardless, when choosing a resistor, you need to consider the power dissipation (resistance and current) so that you can specify the proper power rating.

Comment: Please check your watt hour calculation. I make it 3600 joules.

Comment: Done and fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Look up the [definition of power on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)).

Power (unit: watt) means energy units per second where the energy unit is joule. So 5 W means 5 joule per second. **Notice how there is no mention of "hour".**

One hour is 3600 seconds so 5 watt during one hour means:

3600 seconds * 5 joule / second = 18000 joule of energy

> *or is it correct to say it dissipates 5 W per hour?*

No that is incorrect. Saying: 18000 joule per hour, would be correct, which is the same as 5 watt for one hour.

Comment: So basicly I can say over 2 hours the component consumes 10Wh if its rated at 5W

Comment: @DanielBashy No, the energy consumed is determined by that actual power dissipated in the resistor, not by the power **rating**.  In a well designed system a resistor rated for 5W would not actually dissipate more than 4W or so...perhaps much less.

Comment: I marked this down as being overly pedantic about joules, watts, seconds and hours while simultaneously failing to clear things up for the OP, who is really confusing power *rating* for power *dissipation*. Not helpful.